# Is this the correct notation for a binomial coefficient?

Tags: notation, binomial-coefficients

I need to show the number of ways in which a specific pattern of 1s and 0s can occur. An important factor is that they always have to be paired. For example, 
with n=2 there are 2 combinations: 10, 01
with n=4 there are 4: 1010,1001,0101,0110
with n=6 there are 8: 101010,101001,100110,100101,010101,011010,010110,011001
with n=8 there are 16 and so on...
What the correct way of writing this? Is it simply $2^{n/2}$ or something like $2 \choose 1$$^{n/2}$?

EDIT: I need a 1 AND a 0 in every 2 numbers but the order in which they arrive doesn't matter.

Comment: How about $2^{n/2}$ ?

Comment: Oh sorry, that's a typo by me. That's what I meant initially. I'm just not sure which form is more correct since they both give the same answer.

Comment: In the $n=4$ case, is 1100 a legit pattern?  And 0011? If not, why not?

Comment: I'd go for the simpler form, unless for some reason you want to emphasize that somewhere along the line you are choosing 1 thing from 2.

Comment: @kimchilover No, it's not a legit pattern in my case. In short, I'm writing an essay on informational cascades where these 1s and 0s represent different signals. This specific question is with regard to a case where no cascade occurs which requires signals to cancel each other out straight away. I hope it makes sense :)

Comment: @Roma Wait $1100$ is not valid? Then what are the rules as to what is valid? Are only $110...00$ and $0...011$ disallowed?

Comment: @lightxbulb Sorry if I didn't make it clear with my examples. Basically, I need a 1 AND a 0 in every 2 numbers but the order in which they arrive doesn't matter.

Comment: @Roma I updated my answer to explain why it is so.

Comment: @Roma: Instead of putting your clarifications in the comments, please put them into the question itself (see the "edit" link).

Comment: @Roma Edited again to provide you with an easy way to generate all such bit strings. Note that also the comparisons of the compressed bitstrings work the same way as for the uncompressed variant. Meaning that if $a=b$ then $c(a) = c(b)$, also $a<b$ then $c(a)<c(b)$, and $a>b$ then $c(a)>c(b)$. So the ordering is preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like $2^{{n}/{2}}$ from the given examples.

Edit:
With the clarification, it seems like every 2 bits (you chop the bitstring into 2 bits pieces) need to have a $0$ and $1$.  This means that the choice is separate for every 2 bits. So you get $2$ possibilities per every $2$ bits ($10$ and $01$), since those are picked independently from each other, and you have $\frac{n}{2}$ two-bits pieces, so you get $2^{n/2}$ possibilities. It's the same as the number of ways of picking a vector of the form $\{0,1\}^{n/2}$. This means that you can actually save your state as a $n/2$ long bitstring, where $0$ can be expanded to $01$ and $1$ to $10$. For example you could encode $011010$ as $011$, effectively halving the necessary space.

Edit 2:
Note that this also means that you can easily generate all such vectors by simply iterating from $0$ to $2^{n/2}-1$ (a for loop) and expanding each digit (in binary) into two:  $0\rightarrow 01$ and $1\rightarrow 10$.